# csv's clumns all get together after importing to SQLite

Tags: pandas, sqlite, csv

I made some dataframe on pandas and executed as csv and imported it to my database SQLite.
but when the table shows, all the columns are put in only one column, meaning it has only one column (rows are divided correct).
I'm just wondering how I can copy csv file properly onto database just as it should be.
Thanks for any of your help!

Comment: Please show the code or commands you used to do this which resulted in incorrect import

Comment: Did you use the sqlite3 shell to import the csv file (https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import) or do it in python with pandas?

Comment: @Shawn you saved me and the entire office!! thanks a lot.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen sorry for late reply. it's all resolved and thanks for your attention anyway!